# reactjs drag and drop between grids not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to create a feature of drag and drop rows between two grids in Reactjs. I tried using several libraries(like ag-grid, react-beautiful-dnd, Kendo UI etc.) but none of them are serving my purpose. Either the library does not support drag and drop between different elements or the feature is not supported in IE11. Can anyone suggest any solution to this.

Thank you.

Comment: try this https://github.com/tom-s/react-drag-sortable

Comment: Thank u for your reply. But I am looking for example to drag and drop between two different grids not sorting/reordering within the same grid. Can u suggest an example for this scenario.